# Override same Model/Controller in 2 different modules

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

How to override same class which exist in 2 different custom modules

Eg:

**1)** I have a file **Result.php**.

from **`Vendor\Module1\Block\Result`**

and almost same **Result.php**

from **`Vendor\Module2\Block\Result`** which overrides

**`Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result`**

**2)** Do i have to give

in **`etc/di` of module1**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module1\Block\Result" />
```

in **`etc/di` of module2**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module2\Block\Result" />
```

in both the modules1 and 2's ?

**3)** I have (say) Index.php from controller suppose.

Do the same procedure applies in etc di for both modules?

**4)** Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins is a better approach because you can specify `sortOrder` on the modifications. Then you can also modify according to your needs, `before`, `after` or `around` the public method you want to modify.

**di.xml** for module1

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="module1-result-plugin" type="Vendor\Module1\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Result\ResultPlugin" disabled="false" sortOrder="20"/>
    </type>
```

**di.xml** for module2

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="module2-result-plugin" type="Vendor\Module2\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Result\ResultPlugin" disabled="false" sortOrder="30"/>
    </type>
```

Here is official documentation for how to use plugins:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Preference should be used for defining public interfaces in your module, example from catalogsearch:

```
<preference for="Magento\Search\Model\SearchCollectionInterface" type="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Search\Collection" />
```

Comment: this will not work if you need to add additional methods